# Unable to install windows-build-tools, The system cannot find the path specified error

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I was running `npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0` so that I can run `npm install --save opencv4nodejs`, but I kept getting errors.

I went online and made a lot of different modifications to my system path but I wasn't able to make any progress. I'm on the latest version of node and npm (if that's `16.1.0`).

I don't know if this might be helpful but I cant find the following path on my local machine in the first place: `C:\Users\Yash Oza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools`

> ```
> C:\> npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0                                                                    
> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported                                            
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\Yash Oza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> npm ERR! command failed 
> npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./dist/index.js
> npm ERR! The system cannot find the path specified.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yash Oza\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-08T02_30_02_509Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Did you try to analyze the log? Share it on eg. Pastebin

Comment: Here's a link to the logs: https://pastebin.com/q21Hvmri